# How many time has Ra's al Ghul used the Lazarus Pits?

Tags: dc, batman

I'm interested in the total number of times Ra's has been in the pits himself. I'm looking for the total number of uses in the main DC storyline/continuity, but I am also interested in totals for other significant continuities (if they exist).

Comment: Do you mean used personally on himself, or does using it on other people count too?

Comment: On himself. Other people is another question I can't type right now.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly (98% sure I am.) he's used the Lazarus pit more times than he can count in the main storyline (Pre New 52)

Comment: Can you reference this?

Comment: I will do my best and will respond whether I do or don't find it.

Comment: They never put a number on it to my knowledge